# How to merge 2 udev rules for same device

Tags: 22.04, lubuntu, udev

I'm running lubuntu 22.04

For PS4 controller connected over usb(not bluetooth) I wrote 2 udev-rules for erase touchpad and soundcard device nodes. I want to achive the 2 rules in only 1 udev rule.
For PS4-controller touchpad

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-disable-PS4-touchpad.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="*Controller Touchpad", RUN+="/bin/rm %E{DEVNAME}", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}=""
```

And for soundcard

```
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", ATTRS{id}=="Controller", RUN+="/bin/rm %E{DEVNAME}", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}=""
```

infos

```
udevadm info -n /dev/input/js0 --attribute-walk 
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0001/input/input24/js0':
    KERNEL=="js0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0001/input/input24':
    KERNELS=="input24"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{capabilities/abs}=="3003f"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ev}=="20001b"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ff}=="107030000 0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/key}=="7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/led}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/msc}=="10"
    ATTRS{capabilities/rel}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/snd}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/sw}=="0"
    ATTRS{id/bustype}=="0003"
    ATTRS{id/product}=="09cc"
    ATTRS{id/vendor}=="054c"
    ATTRS{id/version}=="8111"
    ATTRS{inhibited}=="0"
    ATTRS{name}=="Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input3"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"
    ATTRS{uniq}=="84:30:95:84:25:d2"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.3/0003:054C:09CC.0001':
    KERNELS=="0003:054C:09CC.0001"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="sony"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"
    ATTRS{firmware_version}=="0xa00a"
    ATTRS{hardware_version}=="0xb40c"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-6:1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6':
    KERNELS=="1-6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="8"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="6"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="09cc"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Sony Interactive Entertainment"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="433320"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="2"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="2000"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="433320"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/persist}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="433044"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="forbidden"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="1"
    ATTRS{product}=="Wireless Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="108161"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0515"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.15.0-91-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="16"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="633964"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="3494680"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="633951"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="2860725"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="250"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{device}=="0xa12f"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="149"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/149}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="3495779"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="forbidden"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x31"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x224d"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="18"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

I'm struggle with the 2 different `SUBSYSTEM=="input"` and `SUBSYSTEM=="sound"`

Thanks for reading long text.